Child component not refreshing upon an action in Parent component
Context
I have a parent component that displays some contacts. I have a child component that display a child records of contact. Parent component has actions to perform on the data in the parent component only. As shown in the picture below.

Problem Statement

When a user selects a contact -
When an action, like update happens in the parent component, child component which is wired to the apex function, goes blank and doesn't fire, hence no data is displayed.

Parent Component (only related code)
Below function is called on the action
setAgencyAccess(contactRoleId, permissionLevel) {
    this.disableComponent();
    setAgencyAccess({ contactRoleId: contactRoleId, permissionLevel:permissionLevel })
        .then(() => {
            this.refreshMyPeopleList();
            this.showToast('success', this.labels.Permission_upd_msg);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.enableComponent();
            this.showToast('error', error.body.message);
        });
}
refreshMyPeopleList() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('refreshmypeople'));
}

refreshMyPeople() Event is defined in the parent component
refreshMyPeople() {
    getMyPeople()
        .then(result => {
            this.myPeopleList =result;
            if(this.contactIdToSelectUser){
                const userToSelect = this.getUserByContactId(this.contactIdToSelectUser);
                this.contactIdToSelectUser = undefined;
                this.selectedUser = userToSelect;
                console.log('userToSelect:', userToSelect);
                this.selectedUsers = [userToSelect.id];
            }
            this.refreshSelectedUser();
            this.enableComponent();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.showToast('error', error.body.message);
            this.refreshSelectedUser();
            this.enableComponent();
        })
}


Child component code 
@api
get selectedUser() {
    return this._selectedUser;
}

set selectedUser(value) {
    if (value) {
        this.userName = value.name;
        this.contactId = value.contactId;
        console.log('contactid-1:', value.contactId);
        this.isAdminUser = value.isAdminUser;
        this.isActiveUser = value.isSalesHubActive;
        console.log('value:' , JSON.stringify(value));
        this.corpRewardsData = undefined;      // reset data array
    }
}

@wire(getCorpRewardContactRole, {contactId: '$contactId'})
wiredData({ error, data }) {
    console.log('contactid-2:', this.contactId);
    if (data) {
        this.corpRewardsData = data;
        this.error = undefined;
    } 
}

Requirement
When the action is performed on parent component or another child of parent component, I want to refresh the child.

I don't see where you are setting your private this._selectedUser to the value in your setter.  So everytime you get selected user, it either returns nothing, or unless somewhere else in the code you have it initialized.
